# ArrayList in Java only prints the last object in the List

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, computer-science

I'm taking an online Computer Science Course for school and I have hit a bump in the road that after two days I still can not figure out, I have turned to the community.

I have written a piece of code that I need to print the catapult distances. I have put these objects in an ArrayList and have developed a class file for the catapult instance. I want my code to print a list of the distances and the MPH at the start of the row (You can see this with the source files below with an example of what I want it to look like). Here is the code I have developed up to this point:

**Catapult.java**

```
public class Catapult {
    static double speed, angle, MPS, Rad, R;

Catapult(double launchSpeed, double launchAngle) {
    angle = launchAngle;
    speed = launchSpeed;

public void convMPHtoMPS() {
    MPS = speed * 0.44704;
}

public void convDegToRad() {
    Rad = Math.toRadians(angle);
}

public void calcDistance() {
    R = (Math.pow(MPS, 2)*Math.sin(2*Rad))/(Math.pow(9.8, 2));
}

public void convMtoFt() {
    R = R * 3.28084;
}

public double getMPH() {
    return speed;
}

public double getAngle() {
    return angle;
}

public double getMetersPerSecond() {
    return MPS;
}

public double getRadians() {
    return Rad;
}

public double getDistance() {
    return R;
}
}
```

**CatapultTester.java**

```
    public static void calcData() {
        int mph = 25;
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            int deg = 25;
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                CP.add(new Catapult(mph, deg));
                //System.out.println(mph);
                //System.out.println(deg);
                deg += 5;   
            }
            mph += 5;
        }
        System.out.println(CP.size());
        Catapult data;
        for (int index = 0; index < CP.size(); index++) {
            data = CP.get(index);
            data.convMPHtoMPS();
            data.convDegToRad();
            data.calcDistance();
            data.convMtoFt();
            //System.out.println(data.getMPH());
            //System.out.println(data.getDistance());
        }
        presentData();
    }
    public static void presentData() {
        Catapult data;
        for (int index = 0; index < CP.size(); index++) {
            data = CP.get(index);
            System.out.printf("%1f", data.getMPH());
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%4.2f", data.getDistance());
            }
        }
    }
```

**Expected Output**

```
MPH    25 deg    30 deg    35 deg    40 deg     45 deg    50 deg
25     distance  distance  distance  distance   distance  distance
30     distance  distance  distance  distance   distance  distance
...
```

Distance is the formula declared in Catapult.java

`R = (Math.pow(MPS, 2)*Math.sin(2*Rad))/Math.pow(9.8)/2));`

Actual Output:

```
MPH    25 deg    30 deg    35 deg    40 deg     45 deg    50 deg
55     20.34     20.34     20.34     20.34      20.34     20.34
55     20.34     20.34     20.34     20.34      20.34     20.34
55     20.34     20.34     20.34     20.34      20.34     20.34
...
```

Thank you all for your help and I apologize for any grammatical errors or confusion with code. I am new to the Java programming language!

Comment: make your code sample smaller....

Comment: `static double speed, angle, MPS, Rad, R;` <- The use of `static` means that no matter how many instances of the class you create, they will ALL have the same values!  `static` is not your friend and you should avoid using it!

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank You Very Much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shouldn't use static variables in your case cause it'll be common of all objects of the class (Catapult)